# What is the right way dynamically adding events?

Tags: jquery, forms, live, dynamic-forms

The goal is, when I focus on the last text line, another one appears below it. Then disable this at a certain number of lines.
I can't seem to figure out what is wrong here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    lineCount = 0;
    $("form#qc").delegate("input:text:last-child", "focus", newTextLine);
});

function newTextLine() {
    newLine = ("<div id='ansInput{0}'>Answer {0}: <input type='text' name='ans1' /></div><!--ans1-->").format(lineCount);
    currentDiv = ("#ansInput{0}").format(lineCount);
    $(currentDiv).after(newLine);
    lineCount = lineCount++;
}
```

this is the HTML page:

```
<form id="qc" name="qc">
<h2>Create New Question!</h2>
<div id="ansInput0">Question: <input type="text" name="Question" /></div><!--question-->
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I get a very very weired result: each time two lines appear and all have index of `0` and all respond the event handler that is suppose to work only for the last one...
Any ideas what's wrong with the code?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ilyaD/wxqBg/)

Also any advice on how to make the code smarter is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, there are some problems in your code.
I'd try it like this:
Cloning the last div, changing the id and clearing the value of the input:

```
$(function() {
    $("#qc>div:last-of-type>input").live('focus', function() {
        $(this).parent().after($(this).parent().clone().attr('id', 'ansInput' + $('#qc>div').length).find('input').val('').end());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7enNF/1/

---

- input:text:last-child selects inputs which are the last child element in their parent. so it would select all the inputs, because each of them is the only (therefore last) child in the ansInput div
- #qc>div:last-of-type>input selects the input in the last div. i used last-of-type because last-child wouldn't match the div, because the submit button is the last child of the form
- the end is necessary because i select the div, then i select the input with "find('input')" to clear the value. if i'd leave it that way it would only insert the input (not the div). So the end() to get back from the input to the div again so that the div will be inserted.

i hope this wasn't too confusing! :)

Comment: @Andy, thanx for the solution but could you name the problems in my code?

Comment: @Andy also, is `$("#qc>div:last-of-type>input")` selecting input in the last div or last input in the div?

Comment: Oh and last one :) why do you use `.end()`?

Comment: @Andy, thanx for the detailed answer, another question is why do you clone it instead of writing a new div? is there an advantage to it?

Comment: In that case it makes not much difference, but if you have many elements you want to append it's shorter and easier to just clone an existing element than recreating it in jquery

Comment: @Andy, thanx, I've posted another question, using parts of your code, you can take a look if you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205692/dynamically-appending-text-lines

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple problems here. First of all, I don't see what the scope is on your lineCount variable based on the code you've provided. Second, just because you're adding an event handler to the new elements you're creating, doesn't mean you're removing it from the old one.

Comment: Could you be more specific please on the first one? the live event doesn't suppose to respond if the last child has changed, i checked it