# Dynamically appending text lines

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, live

The goal of the code is to create a new input line each time the last line is focused, until a certain amount of lines.
I was offered [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6155018/747024) which works great:

```
$(function() {
    $("#qc>div:last-of-type>input").live('focus', function() {
        $(this).parent().after($(this).parent().clone().attr('id', 'ansInput' + $('#qc>div').length).find('input').val('').end());
    });
});
```

but I also want to change each time the text before the line, so `clone` won't cut it

I modified it to write a pre-ready HTML line, but it doesn't work:

```
function questionsForm() {
    $("#qc>div:last-of-type>input").live('focus', function() {

        lineNum = $('#qc>div').length
        newLine = ("<div id='ansInput{0}'>Answer {0}: <input type='text' name='ans{0}' /></div><!--ans1-->").format(lineNum);

        if ($('#qc>div').length <= 4) { 
            $(this).parent().after(newLine);
        }
    });
}
```

(the `.format` method is predefined)

I would like to understand why my code isn't working, and how to chamge it, but not completely different solutions (unless of course my code has some fundamental errors..)

Comment: is the newLine what you are expecting it to be (if you debug it)? is the function executing on focus of the input? focus and live interact strangely in some browsers.

Comment: for some reason the function won't execute when there is a variable or string in `.after` the chrome debugger gives no errors

Comment: perhaps there is something invalid in newLine? try using a really basic html string and see if that works.

Comment: @aepheus, nope.. could there be a closure problem with the variables?

Comment: is $(this) and $(this).parent() the elements you are expecting? use .html() to see what they are.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a semicolon after `lineNum = $('#qc>div').length`

why is that code in the questionsForm() function?
you could just place it in the jquery ready function `$(function(){ ... });`

Also what does your format function look like?

Comment: (1) thanx for the semicolon, but no change (2) I already have a `$(function(){})` in my code so I put `questionsForm` there (3) the format works fine in other parts of the same code, and I tried to remove it but nothing changed..

Comment: when/where are you calling questionsForm()?

Comment: when I use your code, with clone, it works! It only stops working when I change it to use the HTML line. this is the code including `.format` and `$(function`: http://jsfiddle.net/ilyaD/x5fqf/

Comment: This is really embarrassing.. :) There were so much little errors that had nothing to do with the code I've published, and my code works perfectly. should I erase the question..?